# can't find FULLTEXT index matching

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I am attempting to get FULLTEXT working with my database.  It was an already existing MyISAM database:

```
id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
disabled TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
owner BIGINT NOT NULL,
category VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
title VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'My Product',
`condition` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new',
summary VARCHAR(96) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Product Details',
quantity TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED,
price DECIMAL(7,2),
status TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED,
released DATE,
freight DECIMAL(5,2),
freightX DECIMAL(5,2),
overview TEXT,
warranty TEXT,
notes TEXT,
specList TEXT,
suspended TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
created DATETIME NOT NULL,
updated DATETIME NOT NULL,
```

So I ran the command:

```
"ALTER TABLE ".PREFIX."Shop ADD FULLTEXT(title,summary,overview,specList)"
```

I got no errors.  I then tried to do a search on the database:

```
"SELECT
    tblShop.id,tblShop.title,tblShop.summary,tblShop.overview,tblShop.specList,tblFilters.PID,tblFilters.filter
FROM
    ".PREFIX."Shop tblShop
INNER JOIN
    ".PREFIX."ShopFilters tblFilters ON tblShop.id = tblFilters.PID
WHERE
    tblShop.disabled='0' AND tblFilters.disabled='0' AND tblFilters.filter IN ('".$filters."') AND MATCH(tblShop.title,tblShop.summary,tblShop.overview,tblShop.specList) AGAINST(\"".$_POST['query']."\")
GROUP BY
    id
HAVING
    COUNT(tblFilters.filter)=".$count."
ORDER BY
    MATCH(tblShop.title) AGAINST(\"".$_POST['query']."\"),title ASC"
```

All I seem to get are errors stating:

```
"Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list"
```

I have confirmed that the index does in fact exist via myPHPAdmin.  I have additionally tried:

```
tblShop.disabled='0' AND tblFilters.disabled='0' AND tblFilters.filter IN ('".$filters."') AND MATCH(tblShop.title,tblShop.summary,tblShop.overview,tblShop.specList) AGAINST(\"".$_POST['query']."\")
tblShop.disabled='0' AND tblFilters.disabled='0' AND tblFilters.filter IN ('".$filters."') AND MATCH(title) AGAINST(\"".$_POST['query']."\")
```

No clue what is going on.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your column list needs to list all columns you defined, or you need another index. You also are open to SQL injections. Parameterize. e.g. `match (title,summary,overview,specList) against ...`

Comment: Are you referring to the first additional attempt "MATCH(tblShop.title,tblShop.summary,tblShop.overview,tblShop.specList) AGAINST(\"".$_POST['query']."\")"?

Comment: Still looking for help if anyone is knowledgeable with what the problem may be.

Comment: Which query are you having issues with?

Comment: The multi-line query, thanks

Comment: Did you fix the column list as I stated in previous comment?

Comment: I don't understand.  It's already in the same order and by name.  Can you provide more details?

Comment: `ORDER BY
    MATCH(tblShop.title) AGAINST(` is not the correct list... or you have 2 full text indices. You should add the `create` table syntax so we can see your full table schema.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189906/discussion-between-user1646428-and-user3783243).